# Is a car really sufficient cover from any grenade?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

A flash-bang grenade is thrown in a parking lot. Somewhere else, in another identical parking lot, a fragmentation grenade is thrown. Can someone use a car as cover to completely avoid the effects of either explosion?

How does cover works in the case of a car used as cover? The rules say that a grenade doesn't affect someone in cover unless it breaks the cover, and I cannot imagine the flash-bang grenade breaking the car — but at the same time, can the car really protect you from it? Similarly, I can't imagine a car being fully destroyed by just a fragmentation grenade, so is it safe cover in that case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I've found on Shadowrun Errata and other challenged rulings on Twitter answered by one of the developers/etc , there is a no dodge rule/debate.  Since a Grenade targets the ground/an area and not an actual player character / enemy, you don't get a dodge chance or anything of the sort.

Let's say you ***could*** , however, take cover behind a car with what little time you have before the Flashbang detonates.  There are two effects a Flashbang has, bright light and deafening sound.  If said character was within the area of effect (30ft I think for a Flashbang?) they would still be disoriented by the sound, if not both the sound and the light, regardless of being behind a vehicle or not.  Both rules and common sense (which rarely applies in these cases to begin with) reason that the character would be afflicted even when taking cover.

Comment: This all sounds fine. But can you take into consideration the multiple possibilities where you replace the flash-bang with a "normal" grenade, or the car with a simple wall. My understanding was that for a grenade to affect you when you're behind cover (a wall for example) it has to "break" the wall before getting to you. And if it can't break the wall, the explosion "bounces".

Comment: Yes, if I were to replace the effective shadowrun affliction of a Flashbang with the AOE damage of a Fragmentation Grenade, I did read a ruling about that.  If a wall with a solid foundation (no cracks/weakened etc) is between you and the grenade, you aren't effected unless the wall breaks with extra damage left over.  I do not believe light and sound waves follow the same ruling, but it's been so long since I've had to make a soundwave ruling in Shadowrun I can't find any relevant sources on shrapnel/Frag grenade VS Flashbang or any other light/sound effects/attacks.

Comment: @Airatome Sensible. And cars don't have a solid foundation anyway, having instead a big gap underneath them that would permit a frag grenade to shred one's legs.

Comment: Based on these comments, I've edited the question to more explicitly ask about the issue they seem to be focusing on. Care to give it a look-over and update this answer?